# Filter a list with regex and sort by most matching

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Suppose I have this array

```
const arr = ["another world", "foo", "bar", "foo-another-bar", "another"]
```

I can filter the array based on the regex `/another/` like this

```
const reg = new RegExp(/another/)
const filteredArr = arr.filter(item => item.match(reg))
```

and this returns `[ 'another world', 'foo-another-bar', 'another' ]`

What I now want is to sort this `filteredArr` based on the most match. i.e. `['another', 'another world', 'foo-another-bar']`

Comment: Please define "most matching" as the example sort is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

After filtration, you can sort by the length of the string. Like this:

```js
const arr = ["another world", "foo", "bar", "foo-another-bar", "another"]

const reg = new RegExp(/another/)
const filteredArr = arr.filter(item => item.match(reg))

const sortedArr = filteredArr.sort(function (a, b) { return a.length - b.length })

console.log(sortedArr)
```